# CMake will not set rPath for specific directory

Tags: macos, cmake

I have encountered what appears to be a CMake bug.

I have been migrating a large project to CMake and have all my libraries installed to `/dir1/lib` and `/dir2/lib`. Initially, the binary rPath contained both directories and compiled and ran fine. Seemingly randomly the executables stopped including `/dir1/lib` in their rPath. I have confirmed that CMake finds the libraries in the `/dir1/lib` because if I remove it from `link_directories`, it will not compile.

If I copy the libraries from `/dir1/lib` to `/dir3/lib` and replace the former with the latter in `link_directories`, `/dir3/lib` will appear in the rPath and the executable will run.

I have tried to isolate the problem. Clearing the CMake build files and cache did not help. Restarting did not help. I also created a simplified test case and CMake simply will not set the rPath for that specific directory.

I am running CMake 3.8.2 on OSX.

Is there any global CMake cache or settings I could reset?

Comment: Provide [mcve], please. Note, that when CMake creates executable, RPATH assigned depends **only** on project's settings (`CMakeLists.txt` script). CMake **doesn't read** RPATH from library files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: That is not possible since like I said, this is a bug that randomly occurred and it is specific to this one computer and that one specific path.

Comment: You write in the question: `I also created a simplified test case and CMake simply will not set the rPath for that specific directory.`. If you **assume** that RPATH **should** be set in the that "simplified test case", provide that test case. Otherwise, what do you want from us? Them problem could be in (broken) compiler, linker, elf-utils, filesystem... just anywhere. Should we *guess* that?